# Linking a library and still fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'OpenVolumeMesh.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker

I really did not want to post on something possibly asked a zillion times, but this is very desperate.

I have a solution named HexEx containing 6 projects. 3 of them do not build due to not finding this lib.

The process I follow:

step 1) Configuration properties>general>configuration type set to .exe

step 2) VC++ directories: Added the path where the .lib is (doubled checked the path is correct through the cmd and checked the name is correct (indeed the name is OpenVolumeMesh.lib although the .lib does not appear in windows)). 
I added the path in executable directories and library directories.

step 2.5) VC++ directories: Added also include path used to create the OpenVolumeMesh.lib

step 3) In linker >general I added the same path to >Additional Library Directories.

step 4) In linker, once more in >Input I added the library (OpenVolumeMesh.lib) to Additional dependencies.

The error I get is:

> 3>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'OpenVolumeMesh.lib'

in 3 out of the 6 projects, I suppose the ones needing it.

Another attempt I tried (and this is probably stupid) was to add #pragma comment(lib,"OpenVolumeMesh.lib") in every .c or c++ file containing code.

The .lib was created by building a previous project of mine. All of this is done in VS 12 2013 x64.

From what I read there must also be some .dll put in windows system32 folder some times? Might this be the problem?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't completely understand what you mean when you say "the name is OpenVolumeMesh.lib although the .lib does not appear in windows". Can you explain a little more?

Comment: I think the answer to "there must also be some .dll put in windows system32 folder some times?" is quite likely "no". You only need to allow your project to find the library. system32 is not typically the place you want to be putting those things.

Comment: When you built OpenVolumeMesh, what is the "Configuration Type" under General Settings? Is it a Dynamic Library or Static Library?

Comment: I mean that in the folder it is called OpenVolumeMesh but when you dir the appropriate folder you get OpenVolumeMesh.lib so there is no need to put a .lib because it will be OpenVolumeMesh.lib.lib after. 
Question b: Static

Comment: Okay. The .lib doesn't appear in Windows File Explorer because of your view settings is what you're saying. If you change your settings to show "Details", you should see extensions. Make sure you're using the .lib extension when you add the .lib as an additional dependency under Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies"  (also try using an absolute path instead of only the file name just to test if you set Additional Library Directories correctly)

Comment: Did the above, but I am getting exactly the same error. Any other idea?

Comment: Please ensure you're modifying the settings for the appropriate configuration (Debug/Release or all) that you are trying to build.